# In Django, how do I return a generated dynamically named document as a download?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I have created a page that takes user input via form fields and then takes that data and generates a document from the information.  It saves it to a specified directory and uses form data to create the file name.  I am trying to then have it redirect to prompt a download of that file as well.  The function inside the page view that indicates the directory and creates the filename is 'makefileandpath()'.  I then create a variable 'docname' and call the function.  It works perfectly.  My  problem is then being able to make this variable work with returning the document as a download.  I've tried to create different functions internally to handle this as well as tried to create another view and use it as an endpoint (*all which can be seen below*), but it won't allow me to call the variable name and the document could be called anything.  I'm not sure how to solve this problem and I have been at this for almost a week now.

Comment: Have you considered storing the filenames in a database, maybe a specific model that holds all filenames of these generated files?

Comment: Thanks. I've just started looking into async. Could I run a async download, have it await the return for the variable name here, and then finish the async download?

Comment: It seems that the file generation view (returning a template) and the file download view (returning `FileResponse`) are 2 different views. In that case you cannot use async/await as far as I know.

Comment: You could also use the session to store the filename in, if a database is not a good option for your use case.

Comment: Thanks. That is helpful. I can't use a database for this, so session's is probably the route I need to go. I've only done a simple tutorial on sessions and didn't really grasp an understanding of it. Any recommendations for where I could learn it aside from just the django documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments to the question, I recommend you look into the possibility of using the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/#module-django.contrib.sessions) to store the filename. It is probably not as good as using a database, but it could work for your use case.

To use the session see the [examples in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/#examples).
Set the filename somewhere in one view:

```
def recruiterscreen(request):
    ...
    request.session['download-filename'] = filename
    ...
```

And check for that in the other view:

```
def download_file(request):
    ...
    filename = request.session.get('download-filename')
    if filename is None:
        print('no filename was set')
        # raise some kind of error or do some redirect
    else:
        # download file
    ...
```

Maybe even remove the filename from the session after the download if you want to ensure that the file can only be downloaded once.